# GAE Google App Engine Static File Pattern Handlers Java equivalent?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm new to Google App Engine/ Java / Python.

I would like to use Java for an app, but I have not yet been able to find the equivalent static file pattern matching like is shown for python (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Pattern_Handlers)

```
    handlers:
- url: /item-(.*?)/category-(.*)
  static_files: archives/\2/items/\1
```

Is there static file pattern matching in the config for Java applications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no Url rewriting rules in GAE java configuration.

However you can write your own Url rewriter filter or use an existing [Url rewriter](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/).