# Routing static files in a java webapp (App Engine)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, url-routing

I'd like to have static files URLs like `/v1_2014-02-18_/img/logo.png` match the static file `/static/v1/img/logo.png`.

This is easy in Python or Go : see [app.yaml : wildcard in URL with static_dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443688/app-yaml-wildcard-in-url-with-static-dir)

I'd like to achieve this with `appengine-web.xml` and `dispatch.xml`, but it's not clear to me how to have the "virtual" folder `v1_2014-02-18_` simply serve the content of the actual folder `/static/v1/`

### Trivia

I use Google App Engine to serve a Java webapp.

I'd like to maximize browser cache longevity, minimize number of requests and still serve the fresh versions of my css/js/png, and I believe [revving filenames](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/) is a best practice to achieve this. Also as adding a variable querystring (`/v1/img/logo.png?2014-02-18`) might cause proxy and cache problems, I prefer to show a variable directory name (`/v1_2014-02-18_/img/logo.png`), pointing to the same underlying server dir.

Comment: The answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045828/gae-google-app-engine-static-file-pattern-handlers-java-equivalent?rq=1 looks pessimistic

Comment: I perform my GAE routing using RESTlet and achieve something similar.  It's an extra framework that you might not want/need though.